# multi textures in fragment shader. I got a low fps

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I'm shadering a picture with  GL20.GL_POINTS. One of the attribution of the points is variable('vKind'in the code). When the attribution changed I should change the Texture simultaneously. The follow is my method. But I got a low fps. What should I do? Any help thanks!

```
        final String fragmentShader = "precision highp float;\n"
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture0;\n" // diffuse texture for
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture1;\n" // diffuse texture for
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture2;\n" // diffuse texture for
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture3;\n" // diffuse texture for
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture4;\n" // diffuse texture for
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture5;\n" // diffuse texture for
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture6;\n" // diffuse texture for
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture7;\n" // diffuse texture for
            + "varying float vRotation;\n"
            + "varying float vKind;\n"
            + "varying vec4 vColor;\n" // input color from vertex shader
            + "void main() {\n"
            + "highp vec2 center = vec2(0.5, 0.5);\n"
            // Translate the center of the point the origin.
            + "highp vec2 centeredPoint = gl_PointCoord - center;\n"
            // Create a rotation matrix using the provided angle
            + "highp mat2 rotation = mat2(cos(vRotation), sin(vRotation),\n"
            + "-sin(vRotation), cos(vRotation)); \n"
            // Perform the rotation.
            + "centeredPoint = centeredPoint*rotation ;\n"
            // Translate the point back to its original position and use
            // that point
            // to get your texture color.
            + "if(vKind==0.0)\n"
            + "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture0, centeredPoint + center);\n"
            + "else if(vKind==1.0)\n"
            + "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture1, centeredPoint + center);\n"
            + "else if(vKind==2.0)\n"
            + "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture2, centeredPoint + center);\n"
            + "else if(vKind==3.0)\n"
            + "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture3, centeredPoint + center);\n"
            + "else if(vKind==4.0)\n"
            + "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture4, centeredPoint + center);\n"
            + "else if(vKind==5.0)\n"
            + "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture5, centeredPoint + center);\n"
            + "else if(vKind==6.0)\n"
            + "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture6, centeredPoint + center);\n"
            + "else\n"
            + "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture7, centeredPoint + center);\n"
            + "gl_FragColor *= vColor;\n"

            // +
            // " gl_FragColor.a = (gl_FragColor.b >= 0.5) ? gl_FragColor.a  : 0.0;\n"
            + "}\n";
```

Comment: It'll be far more cache/divergence friendly if you group and draw all points using each texture in turn.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to analyze the situation if the textures are indeed what holds you down: Comment out all but 1 texture and make all the if statements call the same texture. Then after you have confirmed consider 2 things:

- Since you are drawing points do you really need a `varying` for `vKind` or is that an `uniform`. You can use 8 draw calls by separating your points into 8 arrays on the CPU depending on which texture should they use and then use only 1 texture in your fragment shader and bind the correct one before every one of the 8 draw calls.
- If you truly need all of this texture data try looking into how to use atlas (merge multiple textures into one) and try to reduce the texture count as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'l have a try.